# IONIC - I'm doing something wrong to change the background on an ionic app and it's taken over by the mobile

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

What do I have to do to make the phone take the background of my Ionic application? It always appears in black.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the ion-header and ion-toolbar elements? Post that html and scss

Comment: I hope you are following what is mentioned at https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your [statusBar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar) settings.

In `app.component.ts` you can use the following values:

- StatusBar.styleDefault
- StatusBar.styleLightContent
- StatusBar.styleBlackTranslucent
- StatusBar.styleBlackOpaque

For example:

```
 initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      //this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.statusBar.styleBlackTranslucent();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
 ...
```

Other options you can find at https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar